# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature in union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have the following union type written in TypeScript:

```
interface SingleLineTextFieldPropTypes {
  multiLine: false;
  value: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  placeholder?: string;
  readOnly?: boolean;
  type?: string;
  className?: string;

  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

interface MultiLineTextFieldPropTypes {
  multiLine: true;
  readOnly?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  placeholder?: string;
  editorState: EditorState;

  onChange: (editorState: EditorState) => void;
}

type PropTypes =
  SingleLineTextFieldPropTypes |
  MultiLineTextFieldPropTypes;
```

(The only relevant member of those interfaces is the `onChange` function)

I am using them in a React component as follows:

```
class Component extends React.Component<PropTypes> {
  render() {
    if (this.props.multiLine === false) {
      return (
        <input
          type={this.props.type}
          readOnly={this.props.readOnly}
          disabled={this.props.disabled}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          value={this.props.value}
          onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            this.props.onChange((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value as string);
         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here is the error
          }}
          className={classnames('ui-textfield', this.props.className)}
        />
      );
    }
    else { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

Now I am getting an error about the `onChange` call:

```
TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((value: string) => void) | ((editorState: EditorState) => void)' has no compatible call signatures.
```

What should I do about it? I saw some other questions on StackOverflow about this topic, but **none of them illustrates my situation**. Thank you!

Comment: Same issue? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17388

Comment: @unional I don't think so. In my case, I expect `PropTypes` to be resolved as a discriminated union, since I have the `multiLine` that should do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `onChange` has different types in the two interfaces, so the resulting type will be:

```
onChange: ((value: string) => void) | ((editorState: EditorState) => void)
```

Typescript will not merge the call signatures so the result will not be callable. If the two interfaces were to have the same signature, that resulting `onChange` would be callable:

```
interface EditorState { }

interface SingleLineTextFieldPropTypes {
    onChange: (value: EditorState) => void;
}
interface MultiLineTextFieldPropTypes {
    onChange: (editorState: EditorState) => void;
}

type PropTypes  = SingleLineTextFieldPropTypes | MultiLineTextFieldPropTypes;
let d: PropTypes;
d.onChange({})
```

**Edit:**
The problem is in your logic you have a field that is either `SingleLineTextFieldPropTypes` or `MultiLineTextFieldPropTypes` and you try to pass to `onChange` a `string`, but `MultiLineTextFieldPropTypes` can't deal with a string as a parameter (at least according to the declaration). You could do one of two things :

1. Change the definition on `MultiLineTextFieldPropTypes` to allow for a string parameter:

   ```
   interface MultiLineTextFieldPropTypes {
       // onChange has two possible signatures, 
       // note you can't use string|EditorState as that would not get merged.
       onChange: {
           (editorState: string) : void
           (editorState: EditorState) : void
       };
   }
   type PropTypes  = SingleLineTextFieldPropTypes | MultiLineTextFieldPropTypes;
   let editor: PropTypes;
   editor.onChange("")
   ```
2. Add a type guard and pass the apropriate parameter type:

   ```
   if(editor.multiLine === true) {
       let state : EditorState = null; // Get the state
       editor.onChange(state) // TS knows editor is MultiLineTextFieldPropTypes because of the check and the way multiLine  is declared.
   }else {
       let value = "" // Get the simple value
       editor.onChange("")  // editor is SingleLineTextFieldPropTypes
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I got that already, but I think you see the need to have different signatures in those interfaces from my code. What would you recommend?

Comment: @Victor added two possible solutions

Comment: Instead I decided to separate my React component into two components. Your solution seems to work however, so I am accepting this answer! Thank you!